# How can I resolve the issue of being unable to connect NuxtLink to pages and components in my Nuxt.js project?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, nuxt.js, nuxtjs3

[Screenshot of the project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mKvv0.png)

I am trying to create NuxtLink components and connect them to pages. Specifically, I want to connect the 'ContactUs' link in my Navbar component to the Contact page. Here's the code snippet I have tried so far

In Navbar/components:

```
"[<li class="nav-item"><NuxtLink to="/contact" class="nav-link click-close">ContactUs</NuxtLink></li>][1]"
```

In pages:

```
"<template>
    <div>
        <section id="contact">
            <h1>Contact</h1>
        </section>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    name: 'contact'
}

</script>"
```

Comment: The page file is `pages/contact.vue`?

Comment: Also, I guess that the navbar file is actually `components/navbar.vue`, correct?

Comment: @learntheropes, yes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your structure is correct, the `name` property is not needed and the routes are defined by the folders and files names.

If the linked page exists by folder and file, the link will work.

I assume you want a layout with a navbar in every page.
In the navbar you want the links to the pages.

If this is the case, this basic configuration will work:

```
app.vue

layout
  default.vue
  
components
  navBar.vue

pages
  index.vue
  contact.vue
```

- app.vue

```
<template>
  <div>
    <NuxtPage />
  </div>
</template>
```

- layout/default.vue

```
<template>
  <div>
    <NavBar />
    <slot />
  </div>
</template>
```

- components/navBar.vue

```
<template>
  <div>
    <NuxtLink to="/">Home</NuxtLink>
    |
    <NuxtLink to="/contact">Contact Us</NuxtLink>
  </div>
</template>
```

- pages/index.vue

```
<template>
  <NuxtLayout>
    <div>This is the homepage</div>
  </NuxtLayout>
</template>
```

- pages/contact.vue

```
<template>
  <NuxtLayout>
    <div>This is the contact page</div>
  </NuxtLayout>
</template>
```

Note that I used [NuxtPage](https://nuxt.com/docs/api/components/nuxt-page) and [NuxtLayout](https://nuxt.com/docs/api/components/nuxt-layout) that are very useful in any project structure.

I created a working reproduction for you [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/nuxt-starter-5lyfsv?file=package.json)

I hope this help.